# Error: Invalid `prisma.server.findUnique()` invocation:

Tags: javascript, prisma, tsx

I might not be asking this correctly I'm still very new to this;

I'm attempting to create a const that checks to see whether the user is a valid member of the server being loaded.

within my layout.tsx in my main routes folder I have the following (extract not the full code)

```
const ServerIdLayout = async ({
    children,
    params,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    params: { serverId: string };
}) => {
    const profile = await currentProfile();

    if (!profile) {
        return redirectToSignIn();
    }

    const server = await db.server.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: params.serverId,
            members: {
                some: {
                    profileId: profile.id
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The error is stating that the where function requires an 'id' or 'id' argument and states that the id is undefined.

Error response:

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.server.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: undefined,
    members: {
      some: {
        profileId: "b04f5e32-6b4b-411d-a63d-34b37c523ffd"
      }
    },
?   AND?: ServerWhereInput | ServerWhereInput[],
?   OR?: ServerWhereInput[],
?   NOT?: ServerWhereInput | ServerWhereInput[],
?   name?: StringFilter | String,
?   imageUrl?: StringFilter | String,
?   inviteCode?: StringFilter | String,
?   profileId?: StringFilter | String,
?   createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
?   updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
?   profile?: ProfileRelationFilter | ProfileWhereInput,
?   channels?: ChannelListRelationFilter
  }
}
```

Argument `where` of type ServerWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` or `id` arguments. Available options are marked with ?.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The code works fine if I use findFirst(); but not findUnique();

for reference my schema.prisma looks like this:

```
model Server {
  id         String @id @unique @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(255)
  name       String
  imageUrl   String @db.Text
  inviteCode String @db.Text

  profileId String
  profile   Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  members  Member[]
  channels Channel[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([profileId])
}
```

and in my .env my DATABASE_URL ends with sslaccept=strict

I have attempted multiple variants within my schema.prisma file and each time ran npx prisma generate && npx prisma db push in my terminal before re-loading my npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

so after going through all my code it turns out my folder was named [serverid] not [serverId]

which was causing my params to not be able to read the URL hence the undefined value